# How can handle node.js version folder wise?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two project in Node.js

like

1. projectA  (work with node -V0.10.25)
2. projectB   (work with node
   -V0.12.5)

How can i handle this, that at a time projectA run with node version V0.10.25 and projectB with node version v0.12.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make Use of Node Version Manager like `n` or `nvm`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Install n node version manager using npm

```
npm install n -g
```

Then install node binaries for `n`

```
n 0.10.25
n 0.12.5
```

Then run your project using n with specific version

```
n use 0.10.25 projectAServer.js

n use 0.12.5 projectBServer.js
```

Comment: i am running with forever then how will i handle it

Comment: you can find the node binary by using "n bin 0.10.25"

Comment: and Use forever start -c /usr/local/n/versions/node/0.10.25/bin/node projectAServer.js

Comment: thanks @Hiren but can you tell me why we are using -c and can you share me link where i can read more about this.

Comment: -c is used for which program to run. As per documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever, it runs node. By defining -c we told forever to run this command (/usr/local/n/versions/node/0.10.25/bin/node) with argument ( projectAServer.js)